# Is there a way to interact with GUI-buttons in worldspace in any way that doesnt involve the mouse? Preferrably a raycast

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Is there a way to detect if you are aiming at a world space button that doesn't involve the mouse in screenspace?

I am trying to "click" a button with a raycast, but this doesn't work without colliders.

You can detect it with pointereventdata, but this just uses the mouse. I also don't need it to be a physics.raycast. It could just be a custom point in screenspace (for example in middle x: .5f, y: .5f) but I tried setting the position of pointereventdata to that, and it still doesn't work.

I just need a way to interact with the button that doesn't involve extra code for calling the button's all functions, but which doesn't use the mouse.

Comment: [GraphicRaycaster](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html)

Comment: I looked at that raycaster, but are you sure you can use that system without using the pointereventdata type? Meaning its kind of forced to be handled with the mouse as a position anyways. If you can avoid this then can you show any way to do it with just a point in the screenspace or something in code? :)

Comment: You might be able to mock the data. The [sample code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) indicates that its possible, although using real mouse data (but I don't see why you couldn't assign the location to *any* point, same would go for other properties).

Comment: Yea! I was thinking the same exact thing. Ive tried setting the m_PointerEventData.position to a Vector2 like (0.5f, 0.5f), and it doesnt react at all. I've even tried vec3 and trying to convert the my vectors to screenspace/viewport using a few functions but nothing works. I think its because if you look up the core "purpose" of the pointereventdata-type it says its not just generically data for any position, but the mouse, or the touchpad, thereby the word pointer i assume^^^

Comment: I just think its a bit silly that you wouldnt be able to even change a position of your choice even in screenspace, considering that all the position is set to in the example is the mouse's pos.

Comment: I've never tried messing with it myself. Sorry.